# python - add dict to another dict

Tags: python-3.x

need to add a dict to another dict, but the 2nd position need to be dinamic.

```
from time import gmtime, strftime

config = {}

def addStr(reason):
    datetime = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime());
    #config[reason] = {}  # uncoment here got error
    config[reason][datetime] = True
    return config

print ( addStr('reason1') )  # {'reason1': {'2017-10-30 20:08:26': True} }
time.sleep(10)
print ( addStr('reason1') ) # {'reason1': {'2017-10-30 20:08:26': True, '2017-10-30 20:08:36': True} }
time.sleep(10)
print ( addStr('reason1') ) # {'reason1': {'2017-10-30 20:08:26': True, '2017-10-30 20:08:36': True, '2017-10-30 20:08:46': True} }
time.sleep(10)
print ( addStr('reason2') ) # {'reason1': {'2017-10-30 20:08:26': True, '2017-10-30 20:08:36': True, '2017-10-30 20:08:46': True}, 'reason2': {'2017-10-30 20:08:56': True} }
```

I'm Getting error:

KeyError: 'reason1'

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly, you want the missing keys to be automatically created.
For that, you need to use a [collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

```
import collections
config = collections.defaultdict(dict)
```

Comment: @JoeIddon: Straight assignment would *replace* not change. That said, you could (at a minor performance cost) use plain `dict` with the `setdefault` method to create the inner `dict` as needed, `config.setdefault(reason, {})[datetime] = True`

Comment: @ShadowRanger Yes, I agree, I got mixed up about how they wanted to add to them once corrected if the `function` was called with the same `key`